# object stack Albahari

Tags: c#, object

Here is example of Albahari

```
public class Stack
{
int position;
object[] data = new object[10]; // Why 10 nor 1? 
public void Push (object obj) { data[position++] = obj; } //do not understood; Why there is no loop
public object Pop() { return data[--position]; } //do not understood Why there is no loop
}

Stack stack = new Stack();
stack.Push ("sausage");
string s = (string) stack.Pop(); // Downcast, so explicit cast is needed
Console.WriteLine (s); // sausage
```

I rewrote code as listened here

```
public class Stack
{

    object[] data = new object[1];
    public void Push(object obj) { data[0] = obj; }
    public object Pop() { return data[0]; }
}

        Stack stack = new Stack();
        stack.Push("abigale ff");
        string s = (string)stack.Pop(); 
        Console.WriteLine(s); // abigale ff
```

Why there is 10 in  `new object[10];` instead of 1 or 100
Why were used increment in data position? I do not understand how data position works.

`{ data[position++] = obj; }` and  `{ return data[--position]; }` How it works without loops?
I try to push 2 values before pop and write it before pop but it shows me only second value

Comment: You need to understand the concept of how Array works. Please refer below https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm

Comment: I knew. But why there is no loops?

Comment: Read the docs about increment operator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator - ++field is different to field++

Comment: Try pushing *two* (different) values (and only then pop them) in the original code and in your code.

Comment: Hans Kesting, I already tried that! Great! But it only shows second value when  I try to write it.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood. This data is array of objects nor object array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disregarding all the problems with this stack class, your refactoring obviously broke it. As alluded to by the comments, the key information you are lacking is actually what the `++` and `--` operator does, which seemingly led you to believe the `position` field was redundant.

[++ Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator)

> The increment operator (++) increments its operand by 1. The increment
>   operator can appear before or after its operand: ++variable and
>   variable++.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The first form is a prefix increment operation. **The result** of the
>   operation **is the value** of the operand **after it has been incremented**.
>
> The second form is a postfix increment operation. **The result** of the
>   operation **is the value** of the operand 
>   before it has been incremented

```
public class Stack
{
    int position;
    object[] data = new object[10]; // Why 10 nor 1? 
    public void Push (object obj) { data[position++] = obj; }
    public object Pop() { return data[--position]; }
}
```

**For example**

When you call `Push` it  gets the value out of the `data` array at `position` then increments `position`

When you call `Pop` it decrements `position` then gets the value out of the `data` array at `position`

---

There is also a nice little example on the increment page, that shows you how it works

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double x;
        x = 1.5;
        Console.WriteLine(++x);
        x = 1.5;
        Console.WriteLine(x++);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
2.5
1.5
2.5
*/
```

Comment: OK, why there is need some incrementing without loop?

Comment: @ifooi Why would you need a loop to add something to the end, or to get the last item, when `position` already holds the index of the last item?

Comment: OK, I do  { data[position] = obj; } and { return data[position]; }  without postfix or prefix decrement and that works. Why do I need ++

Comment: @ifooi if you pop again or push again it just overwrites element 0

Comment: Now I understood)